# I a facing a issue. I want convert data table data in protobuf format. My table return me columns like this

Tags: protobuf-net

I a facing a issue. I want convert data table data in protobuf format. My table return me columns like this.

ID  Name    CellNo          City    Country
1   Jhon    +923462138434   KHI Pakistan
2   Own +923462138435   LHR Pakistan

I want to convert this format to protobuf format.
There is following code I was trying…
[WebMethod]
    public string Get_OrderInfo(string Token)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();

```
    conn.Open();

    comm.Connection = conn;
    comm.CommandText = "SP_GetAll_Info";
    comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    comm.CommandTimeout = 0;

    comm.Parameters.Add("@Token", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Token;
    SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    reader.
        reader.RemotingFormat = SerializationFormat.Binary;



    conn.Close(); SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO you should do this as two steps:

1. Load the data into an object model - a class with properties that match the columns; Dapper would make this effortless
2. Serialize that class via protobuf; since you mention protobuf-net, this is simply a case of adding the attributes with the tags

However! I don't know how to integrate custom serialization with `[WebMethod]`. You can't really do it by returning a `string`, because protobuf isn't text, unless you're going to base-64 encode it, which would add overhead

Comment: it's not use full.

Comment: @ShahKamran in what way? please be specific about what you're trying to achieve; ultimately, a `DataTable` is never going to be a perfect match for protobuf; you can *hack it*, but it is... not great; but if that's what you want: the following is **completely unsupported**, enjoy: https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/tree/master/assorted/DataTableSerializer

Comment: I need these kind of code that convert datatable to protobuf. This is sample code using json.                       using Newtonsoft.JSON;  

public string DataTableToJSONWithJSONNet(DataTable table)
 {  
   string JSONString=string.Empty;  
   JSONString = JSONConvert.SerializeObject(table);  
   return JSONString;  
}

Comment: @ShahKamran the code l linked to you **does exactly that** - `DataTable` to protobuf binary. Look at program.cs - `ProtoWrite(DataTable table, Stream stream)` and `DataTable ProtoRead(Stream stream)`.